# Functions arcpy don't retrieve data

Tags: arcpy

I try to run python script with these functions:

arcpy.ListTables()

, arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

or

,arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "FileGDB")

but all the functions return right results on one computer and return "None"  on another.

Folder with GDB files was copied to both of these computers and has access by ArcCatalog correctly from the both computers.

What might be the problem? May be any security?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved.The path "d:\geodb\any.gdb" was specified in the configuration file. This representation of the path is correct for arcpy for the first computer, but invalid for the second computer. The path was rewritten in the following form "d:/geodb\any.gdb" (backslash and two slashes) for the second computer. The both computers have the same OS version (windows 10). I don't know what settings do this depend on.